# Invalid argument: File not found using page-object gem inside docker

Tags: ruby, docker, cucumber, page-object-gem

I'm running some browser based UI tests inside a docker container using page-object gem by Cheezy.

Here's the code in question that's not working:

```
file_field(:the_file, name: 'file_source')

def upload_file(csv_file)
  puts "CURRENT DIR: #{Dir.pwd}"
  self.the_file = Dir.pwd + "/config/data/#{csv_file}"
  sleep(1)
  upload_button
end
```

Command:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/app ruby:2.4 bash -c "cd /app && bundle install && /app/cucumber-command.sh"
```

cucumber-command.sh:

```
cucumber RUN_ON_BSTACK=true --tags @send_request --format pretty --format junit --out results
```

Error:

```
CURRENT DIR: /app
...
invalid argument: File not found : /app/config/data/GDPR.csv
```

However, the file exists inside the container:

```
# ls -l /app/config/data/GDPR.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 staff 11602 Jul 11 03:05 /app/config/data/GDPR.csv
```

The problematic line is this one:

```
self.the_file = Dir.pwd + "/config/data/#{csv_file}"
```

**This works fine if I don't run it inside the docker container.**

One interesting thing that I found was that the Error was different when I gave it another path:

```
No such file or directory - /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tests/config/data/GDPR.csv (Errno::ENOENT)
(eval):1:in `process_watir_call'
```

Which seems like the real error of not finding a file.

`file_field` is not able to find the file when executed inside the container. Could someone help me understand what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: I think I know why this is happening. I'm running these tests on BrowserStack remote system and I might need to use a 'file detector' before I upload/find it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I needed a file_detector that would allow the files to be uploaded on a remote system (BrowserStack)

Here's the code in my hooks.rb that fixed it:

```
browser.driver.file_detector = lambda do |args|
  str = args.first.to_s
  str if File.exist?(str)
end
```